# Switch between two images on state condition

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework

I have an image(button) and i want to switch the image when the state is false i have the initial one when state is true i want to have another one.

the html file

```
<img class="sig"  [src]="picToView" (click)="hand($event)" src="assets/imgs/second.png">
```

the ts file

```
  hand(event){
      this.status = !this.status
      this.picToView="assets/imgs/first.png"
  }
```

At the moment when i click, the image change and when i click again i don't get the initial back.
I think i need to link the changing of the images with the state

Is there a way to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like below:

```
hand(event){
      this.status = !this.status
      if(this.status === false) {
        this.picToView="assets/imgs/first.png" // URL of image to be rendered when status is false
      } else {
        this.picToView="assets/imgs/original.png" // URL of image to be rendered when status is true
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
hand(event) {
    this.status = !this.status
    this.picToView = `assets/imgs/${this.status ? "first" : "second"}.png`
}
```